# Geo Nodes: Change the H/S/V of an Instances Material per Mesh Island (without realizing them)

Tags: geometry-nodes, color, instances

I work on a Node Setup with which I can spawn Houses on Faces. Now I want to make the instanced House Fassades the same Color as the Face it´s been spawned on while only using one Mastermaterial for the Fassades.

More detailed:

- I give several Faces in one Object a random H/S/V-Shift per Mesh Island in it´s Material (Attributes on the left in the Shader Editor).
- I want to spawn Instances on these Faces and the Instances Material shall get the same H/S/V-Shift, the Face itself got. The red Roofs have a separate Material and they shall stay that way.
- Right now the Instances have all the same Color. Can I achieve this without realizing the Geometry? Because that would make my scene too heavy.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT:
@Crantisz I don´t know if I understand you correctly, right now everything has the same color:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use instances, there is no need in Mesh Island node. Do the following:

1. Switch the Mesh Island to Random node
2. Change attribute domain of Geometry nodes output from vertex to instance (<kbd>N</kbd> Panel)

[image]

3. In the Attribute node set type to Instancer

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think I don´t understand it right. I´ve added a Pic in my Post :)

Comment: random value makes a number from 0 to 1 plug it directly to color ramp

Comment: Ah okay, I got what you mean. But now the groundplanes on which I spawn the Instances are pitch black. But I want them to have a different color aswell. And it should be the same color, the Instances get... The groundplanes shall be all in one Object.

Comment: I see. Ground planes are not instances, so this doesn't work. Should be separate material then.

Comment: oh yeah thank you, with different Materials it´s pretty easy :)